# How to apply coupon code only to normal price not special price

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, special-price

I created one shopping cart rule for *10% discount* using coupon code `tenoff` for all products but I want to apply this discount only on products which don't have active special price. Is this possible? how can I achieve this?

I m applying following rule :

If ALL  of these conditions are FALSE :
Special Price  equals or greater than  0.1

But this is working fine for special price which is not expired, now if special price expired then above rule is not working.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Create an issue on m2 git? They will be able to spin up a virtual instance to check whether still issue in latest release.

Comment: do you have an idea how to avoid  discount for special price ?

Comment: Not aware it can be done. You would have to rework your rules and possibly make changes to frontend https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Discount-Rules-I-want-them-applied-to-base-price/td-p/78265

Comment: If special price expired then in this case I should definitely not work because their is not any special price for this product its price is normal after expiration.